# CSV Data Parsing using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need some help in transforming an input data which is from reading a csv file. I would like to convert it into a structure that is a little more intelligent. I was thinking there is probably some cumulative processing, but not sure how to go about it.

My input XML:

```
<lines>
    <line number="1">Header, some header data 1</line>
    <line number="2">Data, some data for 1</line>
    <line number="3">Data, some data for 1</line>
    <line number="4">Header, some header data for 2</line>
    <line number="5">Data some data for 2</line>
</lines>
```

Required output is to classify into chunks using the word Header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lines>
    <Block>
        <line number="1">Header, some header data 1</line>
        <line number="2">Data, some data for 1</line>
        <line number="3">Data, some data for 1</line>
    </Block>
    <Block>
        <line number="4">Header, some header data for 2</line>
        <line number="5">Data some data for 2</line>
    </Block>
</lines>
```

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="line[not(substring-before(.,',')='Header')]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::line[substring-before(.,',')='Header'][1])"
  />

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <lines>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*[substring-before(.,',')='Header']"/>
     </lines>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="line">
  <Block>
    <xsl:copy-of select=".|key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
  </Block>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<lines>
    <line number="1">Header, some header data 1</line>
    <line number="2">Data, some data for 1</line>
    <line number="3">Data, some data for 1</line>
    <line number="4">Header, some header data for 2</line>
    <line number="5">Data some data for 2</line>
</lines>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<lines>
   <Block>
      <line number="1">Header, some header data 1</line>
      <line number="2">Data, some data for 1</line>
      <line number="3">Data, some data for 1</line>
   </Block>
   <Block>
      <line number="4">Header, some header data for 2</line>
      <line number="5">Data some data for 2</line>
   </Block>
</lines>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I was completely lost and not able to get started on this.